# how to properly make a vertical recycler view inside a scroll view that will not slow the fragment to appear?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to make UI like this:

[image]

as you can see, there is a vertical recycler view there. that recycler view is inside scroll view. so I want to make the screen can be scrolled down as much as item data in the recycler view. here is the xml I use:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" 
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_user_control"
    tools:context=".Fragments.UserControl.UserControlFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout                                                
        android:layout_width="match_parent"                                           
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                                      
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_profile">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_profile_image_user_control"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/user"
            app:civ_border_width="0.5dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000" 
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp" 
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="User Fullname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView_user_fullname_user_control" 
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_profile_image_user_control"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="user@email.com"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView_user_email_user_control" 
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_user_fullname_user_control"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="AKAN DIHADIRI"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView_will_come_user_control" 
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_user_email_user_control"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingStart="16dp" android:background="#D2D1D6"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_will_come_user_control"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_general_event" 
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_attended_event_user_control"/>

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView_gear_setting_user_control"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_profile_image_user_control"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

if I fetch 20 data from server and set it those 20 items to the recycler view, it will make my app slow, I mean the fragment will appear around 2 seconds after fragment transaction.

If I limit the data to be only one data that fetched from server that need to be shown to recycler view. it will make my app faster.

so it clears that, the more items in the recycler view inside scroll view, the more slower it takes to show the fragment.

here is my code :

```
class UserControlFragment : Fragment() {


    lateinit var progressBar : ProgressBar
    lateinit var gearSettingImageView: ImageView
    lateinit var emailTextView: TextView
    lateinit var userFullNameTextView :TextView
    lateinit var profilePictureImageView : ImageView
    lateinit var fragmentView : View
    lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView

    lateinit var sharedPrefManager : SharedPreferenceManager
    lateinit var eventAdapter : GeneralEventRecyclerViewAdapter


    private var attendedEvents = ArrayList<Event>()
    private var userData : User? = null

    lateinit var mContext : Context
    lateinit var mActivity : FragmentActivity

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        mContext = context
        activity?.let { mActivity = it }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_control, container, false)
        sharedPrefManager = SharedPreferenceManager.getInstance(mContext)
        setUpViewsDeclaration()


        getUserData()
        updateUI()

        initRecyclerView()




        return fragmentView
    }

    private fun setUpViewsDeclaration() {

        progressBar = mActivity.progressBar_main_activity
        gearSettingImageView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_gear_setting_user_control)
        emailTextView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView_user_email_user_control)
        profilePictureImageView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_profile_image_user_control)
        userFullNameTextView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView_user_fullname_user_control)
        recyclerView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_attended_event_user_control)



    }


    private fun getUserData() {
        userData = sharedPrefManager.loadUserData()

        if (userData == null) {
            performLogOut()
            return
        }

        getAttendedEvents()


    }

    private fun updateUI() {

        userData?.let {

            userFullNameTextView.text = it.fullname
            emailTextView.text = it.email

            Picasso.get()
                .load(it.profilePicturePath)
                .into(profilePictureImageView)
        }

    }



    private fun initRecyclerView() {

        eventAdapter = GeneralEventRecyclerViewAdapter(mContext)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(mContext, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
        recyclerView.adapter = eventAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false

        eventAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object: OnEventKMListener {

            override fun eventKMClicked(position: Int) {
                val selectedEvent = attendedEvents[position]
                val eventDetailDestination = UserControlFragmentDirections.actionGlobalDestinationEventDetail(selectedEvent)
                Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigate(eventDetailDestination)
            }

        })




    }


    private fun getAttendedEvents() {

        showLoadingState(true)

        FirestoreKMClient.getRecommendedEvents(userData!!.domicile) { errorMessage, events ->

            errorMessage?.let {
                activity?.toast(it)
            } ?: run {

                val eventList = events ?: ArrayList()
                attendedEvents = eventList
                eventAdapter.submitList(eventList)

                showLoadingState(false)

            }

        }


    }


    private fun showLoadingState(enabled: Boolean) {

        if (enabled) {
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

    }


}
```

I have tried to move the background processing from onCreateView to onResume but it doesn't make any effect.

so how to solve this ? Java is OK

Comment: You can use `NesteadScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` and make your `RecyclerView` `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`

Comment: You can set your top-view as an item in `RecyclerView`. That way you don't have to use `ScrollView`.

Comment: @NileshRathod unfortunately it doesn't work in my case

Comment: @user10284284 is it a common practise to do that ? so the scroll view makes my app slower ?

Comment: I once had a similar problem in my App. I tried using `NestedScrollView` but it didn't worked for me, so I ended up using this method to resolve it.